# Exporting events from Google calendar to Google Sheets without the formatting found in the text as in

Tags: api, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

Exporting events from Google calendar to Google Sheets without the formatting found in the                      text as in the image. How do I download it?\

[image: 1]

```
function getEvents2022() {//חודש 0122var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("0122");
```

```
var start_time = sheet.getRange("A2").getValue();var end_time = sheet.getRange("B2").getValue();var id_cal = sheet.getRange("C2").getValue();
```

```
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("AAA@gmail.com");
var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("01/01/2022 12:00 AM"), new Date("01/31/2022 11:59 PM"));

for (var i = 0;i\<events.length;i++){

var title =  events[i].getTitle();
var start_time =  events[i].getStartTime();
var end_time =  events[i].getEndTime();
var loc = events[i].getLocation();
var des =  events[i].getDescription();
var vis = events[i].getVisibility();

sheet.getRange(i+2,1).setValue(title);
sheet.getRange(i+2,2).setValue(start_time);
sheet.getRange(i+2,3).setValue(end_time);
sheet.getRange(i+2,4).setValue(loc);
sheet.getRange(i+2,5).setValue(des);
sheet.getRange(i+2,6).setValue(vis);
}
```

Comment: Not being familiar with Google Skillshop, how do you get the html that is shown in each cell?

Comment: Exporting events from Google calendar to Google Sheets without the formatting found in the text as in the image. How do I download it?

Comment: Use calendar methods to obtain them.

Comment: How do I get them? I want to delete these English letters from the document! Clear!! I import it from Apps script

Comment: I've tried to duplicate your situation.  I have a calendar event with a descripition.  It appears as plain text with non-visable new line to break it into multiple lines.  When I `getDescription()` I do not see html line breaks `<br>` .  It shows up in the cell as a multi line string.  Where do the html `<br>` come from?

Comment: If you add an event and add in the description text + space + enter + bold + slash it will show you

Comment: Yes now I see it.

Comment: Do you want <br> to be translated to new line `\n`?

Comment: No. I want it to arrive at all with the information from the calendar

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want but try it.

```
let events = calendar.getEvents(start,end);
let desc = [];
events.forEach( event => {
    let text = event.getDescription();
    text = text.replace(/<.+?>/gm,"");
    console.log(text);
  }
);
```

Reference

- [RegExr](https://regexr.com/)

Comment: Where do I put this in the code?

Comment: And what does it do?